# Turn text around a certain character in python

Tags: python, string, substring

I need to code a program that sort of turns text around a given character and deletes that character. The outcome will be sort of simple ASCII art. You need to input the character where the text will be turned around, and the amount of lines that the given input will be. An example would be:
Input:

```
|
26
                   |                          oooo$$$$$$$$$$$$oooo          
      |                      oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o                    
$o         o$   $$ o$    |                   oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o       $$ $$ $$o$   |   o $ oo        o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    $$$o$$o$    |oo $ $ "$      o$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$o   
$$$$$$$o    $$$$$$$$     |"$$$$$$o$     o$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$
$$     |  $$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$  """$$$       |  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$  
$$$$$$$$$     "$$$      |   "$$$""""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$$$$$     "$$$o    |    $$$   o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$$o   |   o$$"   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$       $
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$" "$$$$$$ooooo$$$$o |   $$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$$$oooo$$$$$  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$   o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$|  o
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     $$$$""""""""      |  $$$$$$$$"$$$$   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"      o$$$               | """"       $$$$    "$$
         "$$$o     """$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"$$"         $$$                |   
          "$$""$$$$$$""""           o$$$                 |              $$$o
            o$$$"                  |               $$$$o                 oo 
                |                "$$$$o      o$$$$$$o"$$$$o        o$$$$    
|                  "$$$$$oo     ""$$$$o$$$$$o   o$$$$""                     
o$$$$$$$$$"""                        |                     ""$$$$$oooo  "$$$
             ""$$$$$$$oo $$$$$$$$$$                             |           
$$$$$$$$$$$                            |                                """"
$$$$$$$$                           |                                    $$$$
                           |                                     $$$$$$$$$$"
                                 "$$$""""                             |
```

output:

```
                          oooo$$$$$$$$$$$$oooo                             
                      oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o                          
                   oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o         o$   $$ o$    
   o $ oo        o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o       $$ $$ $$o$   
oo $ $ "$      o$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$o       $$$o$$o$    
"$$$$$$o$     o$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$o    $$$$$$$$     
  $$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     
  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$  """$$$       
   "$$$""""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     "$$$      
    $$$   o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     "$$$o    
   o$$"   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$       $$$o   
   $$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$" "$$$$$$ooooo$$$$o 
  o$$$oooo$$$$$  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$   o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
  $$$$$$$$"$$$$   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     $$$$""""""""      
 """"       $$$$    "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"      o$$$               
            "$$$o     """$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"$$"         $$$                
              $$$o          "$$""$$$$$$""""           o$$$                 
               $$$$o                 oo             o$$$"                  
                "$$$$o      o$$$$$$o"$$$$o        o$$$$                    
                  "$$$$$oo     ""$$$$o$$$$$o   o$$$$""                     
                     ""$$$$$oooo  "$$$o$$$$$$$$$"""                        
                        ""$$$$$$$oo $$$$$$$$$$                             
                                """"$$$$$$$$$$$                            
                                    $$$$$$$$$$$$                           
                                     $$$$$$$$$$"                           
                                      "$$$""""
```

I assume I would have to use substrings in order to do this, but I'm not sure how exactly I would have to do this. (sorry for bad explanation/english)

Comment: Use `split()` to separate a string at a delimiter.

Comment: What does "turns text around a given character" mean? Reverse a part of the two substrings? If so, which part?

Comment: Use `s[::-1]` to reverse a string `s`.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: it doesnt really mean reverse the string, im sorry i worded it badly, it should print the part after the character first, and then print the part that was before the character

Comment: What character? All items in a string are characters.

Comment: in this case it is "|" but the user should input it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not too difficult. It helps to start with a plan of how you want to attack it.

1. Start by getting the `delimiter` character and `length` using
   `input` and create a variable to store the result.
2. Create a for loop that runs for `length` iterations.
3. Get each line by calling `input` and split each line by the `delimiter`
4. Reverse the start and end, and then add it to the result.

You could have something like this:

```
delimiter = input()
length = int(input())
result = ""

for i in range(length):
    line = input()
    [end, start] = line.split(delimiter)
    result += start + end + "\n"

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the separator and lines in separate variables, you can use split to get the inverted left and right sides and print them in the correct order:

```
s = '''|
26
                   |                          oooo$$$$$$$$$$$$oooo          
      |                      oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o                    
$o         o$   $$ o$    |                   oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o       $$ $$ $$o$   |   o $ oo        o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    $$$o$$o$    |oo $ $ "$      o$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$o   
$$$$$$$o    $$$$$$$$     |"$$$$$$o$     o$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$
$$     |  $$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$  """$$$       |  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$  
$$$$$$$$$     "$$$      |   "$$$""""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$$$$$     "$$$o    |    $$$   o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$$o   |   o$$"   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$       $
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$" "$$$$$$ooooo$$$$o |   $$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$$$oooo$$$$$  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$   o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$|  o
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     $$$$""""""""      |  $$$$$$$$"$$$$   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"      o$$$               | """"       $$$$    "$$
         "$$$o     """$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"$$"         $$$                |   
          "$$""$$$$$$""""           o$$$                 |              $$$o
            o$$$"                  |               $$$$o                 oo 
                |                "$$$$o      o$$$$$$o"$$$$o        o$$$$    
|                  "$$$$$oo     ""$$$$o$$$$$o   o$$$$""                     
o$$$$$$$$$"""                        |                     ""$$$$$oooo  "$$$
             ""$$$$$$$oo $$$$$$$$$$                             |           
$$$$$$$$$$$                            |                                """"
$$$$$$$$                           |                                    $$$$
                           |                                     $$$$$$$$$$"
                                 "$$$""""                             |     '''
separator,count,*lines = s.split("\n")
for line in lines:
    right,left = line.split(separator)
    print(left+right)
```

output:

```
                          oooo$$$$$$$$$$$$oooo                             
                      oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o                          
                   oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o         o$   $$ o$    
   o $ oo        o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o       $$ $$ $$o$   
oo $ $ "$      o$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$o       $$$o$$o$    
"$$$$$$o$     o$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$o    $$$$$$$$     
  $$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$      $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     
  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$  """$$$       
   "$$$""""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     "$$$      
    $$$   o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     "$$$o    
   o$$"   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$       $$$o   
   $$$    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$" "$$$$$$ooooo$$$$o 
  o$$$oooo$$$$$  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$   o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
  $$$$$$$$"$$$$   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$     $$$$""""""""      
 """"       $$$$    "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"      o$$$               
            "$$$o     """$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"$$"         $$$                
              $$$o          "$$""$$$$$$""""           o$$$                 
               $$$$o                 oo             o$$$"                  
                "$$$$o      o$$$$$$o"$$$$o        o$$$$                    
                  "$$$$$oo     ""$$$$o$$$$$o   o$$$$""                     
                     ""$$$$$oooo  "$$$o$$$$$$$$$"""                        
                        ""$$$$$$$oo $$$$$$$$$$                             
                                """"$$$$$$$$$$$                            
                                    $$$$$$$$$$$$                           
                                     $$$$$$$$$$"                           
                                      "$$$""""
```